# Left side of UISplitViewController is blank in landscape mode after dismissing popoverController in portrait mode

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

1. I present the popoverController from View A(UISplitViewController) and dismiss it in portrait mode.
2. I switch to another View B using ECSlidingDrawer.
3. Change orientation to landscape mode.
4. Switch back to View A with landscape mode.
5. The left side of the UISplitViewController is now blank.

If I change the orientation to portrait and back to landscape again from step 5, the left view will be shown again.

Anyone know what is the problem?

I found that the

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
```

in View A is not called when the orientation is changed to landscape from another View B.
Is that what it makes the left side of splitView not showing?

Comment: set frame in shoudAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation Method

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation or shouldAutoRotate in the DetailView of SplitView are both not called when i rotate the device